# How to update the bios of a Dell Optiplex GX280 with Windows XP?

Tags: boot, bios

My computer BIOS for Dell Optiplex GX280 with XP Pro has been failing me miserably. So, I have decived to update/replace the BIOS. Now, my questions are: What files do I put on that bootable floppy? Where can I find those files? Any help and pointers will be gladly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a floppy.

**[Installation Instructions](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen&releaseid=R119219&SystemID=PLX_GX280&servicetag=&os=WW1&osl=en&deviceid=162&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=7&catid=-1&impid=-1&formatcnt=1&libid=1&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&fileid=158334)**

> The file GX280A07.exe is using the
>   Universal (Windows/ DOS) format and is
>   designed to be **directly executed from Windows environment**.
>
> Click Download now.The File Download
>   window appears.
>
> Click the Save button.The Save As
>   window appears.
>
> Select Desktop using the drop-down
>   menu to the right of Save in.
>
> Click the Save button.A progress meter
>   moves as the download is completed.
>
> If necessary, click X in the upper
>   right-hand corner of the Download
>   Progress Window to close it upon
>   completion.
>
> NOTE: Shut down all other applications
>   prior to running the BIOS update
>   utility. The update utility reboots
>   your system in order to get the new
>   BIOS loaded.

Having said that, "XP Pro failing you miserably" is hardly related to an older BIOS, the reasons for that are usually to be found elsewhere.

Read the change log and decide if you really benefit from the upgrade.

Here is what the latest BIOS does:

1. Update Video Option ROM to version 1235.
2. Improve keyboard parser functionality.
3. Add Service Tag edit feature in Setup.
4. Improve detach support for USB keyboards.

Comment: I have already download this and put it on a floppy. However, since my computer can only boot from Floppy at the moment, the system did not recognized the .EXE file. Any tips on how to go around that?

Do you think it will make a difference if I use the harddrive on a another computer and do the update and afterward put it back on the damaged pc? Will that updated/replace the BIOS?

Comment: "BIOS for Dell Optiplex GX280 with XP Pro" i only gave the OS just in case you needed to know. The BIOS is my problem, NOT the OS.

Comment: so your Windows XP installation is not booting anymore? and what leads you to the conclusion that this could be fixed with a BIOS update? you can install XP on another HDD and then apply the BIOS upgrade (which has to be done within Windows). IF this will fix the issue, all you'll have to do is fitting the old HDD again and all should be well, however, i really doubt it. and NO, you can't use this HDD in another Computer and run the BIOS upgrade there, this has to be done on the Optiplex.